# How do I connect VS2010 to a MySQL database (locallay on another computer)?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, installation, local

I have a MySQL database on another windows computer (a server) that is setup locally using remote desktop connection for testing.

How can I connect to that local database to Visual Studio 2010 on "my computer"?

Server Computer(MySQL database setup local) --> My Computer(Visual Studio for test code..)

I am new to MySQL and any suggestions will help.

Thanks

PS: I have found this, but the "Server Name" for the database is 127.0.0.1 which I can't use because it is local on whatever computer you are on.

http://geekswithblogs.net/mbridge/archive/2010/12/13/visual-studio-2010-hosting--connect-to-mysql-database-from.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use the address of the computer that it is hosted on.  It should be the same as the address you use to connect to the remote desktop session.

You might need to configure the firewall to accept the connection.  You also might need to setup MySQL to allow remote connections with the user that you authenticate with.

I would recommend downloading MySQL workbench and install it on your local computer.  Once you get the connection working with that, you should be able to use the connection with VS2010.

If you're not sure how to do the things listed above, you'll need to start out with a basic tutorial on setting up MySQL for remote connectivity.